# how to remove incomplete data for longitudinal data in long format?

Tags: r

Here is a reproducible test dataset

```
mydata <- structure(list(subject = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), time = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2), measure = c(10, 12, 8, 7, 0, 0, 5, 3, NA)), .Names = c("subject", "time", "measure"), row.names = 1:9, class = "data.frame")

mydata

subject  time  measure
1          0      10
1          1      12
1          2       8
2          0       7
2          1       0
2          2       0
3          0       5
3          1       3
3          2      NA
```

I would like to remove all the rows where `measure` is NA *and* all the corresponding rows for the same `subject`. So in the example above that would yield:

```
subject  time  measure
1          0      10
1          1      12
1          2       8
2          0       7
2          1       0
2          2       0
```

Is there an easy way to do this without reshaping to wide format first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this needs `reshaping` or even `ave`. It is just a `subsetting` issue, if I understand your question right.

```
mydata[!with(mydata, subject %in% subject[is.na(measure)]), ]

#   subject time measure
# 1       1    0      10
# 2       1    1      12
# 3       1    2       8
# 4       2    0       7
# 5       2    1       0
# 6       2    2       0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
mydata[with(mydata, as.logical(ave(measure, subject, FUN=function(x) ifelse(any(is.na(x)), 0, 1)))),]
#   subject time measure
# 1       1    0      10
# 2       1    1      12
# 3       1    2       8
# 4       2    0       7
# 5       2    1       0
# 6       2    2       0
```